# Magento - Canonicals are not set

Tags: seo, canonical

I changed the settings in my Magento store to use Canonical URLs:

`System > Configuration > Catalog > Search Engine Optimizations`. Then I selected Yes for `Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Categories` and  `Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Products`. I have cleared the cache and opened up my product, checked the source code for "canonical" and nothing can be found.

How can that be? Any hints how I can solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share a link to your site?

Comment: @Klettseb: Sure: https://frischepost.com/hamburg/apfel-rhabarber-saft.html and https://frischepost.com/hamburg/speisekammer/apfel-rhabarber-saft.html

Comment: Mh ok, are your indexes up to date?

Comment: Yep. Is it likely, that the code in my template is not available? Do you know where the canonical Tags is set in Magento's template files?

Comment: In app/\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Category\View.php and app/\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\View.php and in your app/\code\core\Mage\Page\Block\Html\Head.php your have the addLinkRel function

Comment: @klettseb Looks like the theme does not support, canonical urls. I have now inserted the code from:
http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/magento-seo-optimizing-pages-and-avoiding-duplicate-content-penalties--cms-22110

Comment: I can´t see it yet but I will look later again :-)

Comment: Thanks. I have to deploy it in the regular cycle - this can take a few days. Thanks for your help @Klettseb